# Removing a part of a string before second /

Tags: java, string

I have following string:

```
String path="/folder1/folder2/folder3/";
```

I want to remove the first path of the String, so that it becomes:

```
String path="/folder2/folder3/";
```

So, what I basically need is to know the index of second backslash and I can use `subString` method then.

In order to know the 2nd position of /, I can run a for loop and check every character.

But I think there must be a better solution. I want to improve my code knowledge. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `path.indexOf('/', 1)` to find the index. This would just skip the first character, which could be a `/` but it would also make sure that, should the first character not be a `/` it would still remove the first part of the path.

```
path = path.substring(path.indexOf('/', 1));
```

There are other answers using Regex, maybe its because im not good with those, but personally I think in such simple cases, its better to avoid using them, to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks, this one simply solved my problem. I also appreciate the regex solution, but may be for more complex solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using a regular expression replacement:

```
String newPath = path.replaceAll("^/[^/]*", "");
```

This means: "after the / at the start of the string (`^/`), match all of the characters up to but not including the next / (`[^/]*`);".

Comment: Good one. But it should replace with an empty string else you'll end up with two leading slashes. `String newPath = path.replaceAll("^/[^/]*", "");`

Comment: Updated to not leave two slashes.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do that. If you **know** that there must be a **second** "/" that implies: there is a **first** one at index 0.
So you could use `String.indexOf(char, index)` - this version of indexOf searches for the first occurrence of the given character **after** the provided index. And when you got that second index, you can run subString().

The other option would be to use a simple regular expression to match the second / (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ for a great introduction to this topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf()` twice:

```
path.indexOf('/', path.indexOf('/')+1))
```

will gives you the second slash of the string path.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest soultion to find second index would be using indexof twice. (You may have to check for -1)

```
String path="/folder1/folder2/folder3/";
int secondIndex = path.indexOf("/", path.indexOf("/") + 1);
System.out.println(path.substring(secondIndex));
```

If you can use apache commons then StringUtils have a method [ordinalIndexOf](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) that does this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String path="/folder1/folder2/folder3/";
path = path.replaceAll("^/[^/]*", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a string which is like String path="folder1/folder2/folder3/";
you can simply split it to form and array and use the same to get your desired index.

but in your case I could see an additional "/" before "folder1", this would result in a blank or empty fist cell, thus you would also have to verify for the content, before using the generated array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use java.lang.String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) if you are sure about occurrence of the "/" at the 0th index.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/";
    String newPath = path
            .substring(path.indexOf("/", 1), path.length());
    System.out.println(newPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the directories as `Path` (or `File`) object you could use the following solution

```
Path path = Paths.get("/folder1/folder2/folder3/");
Path removedTopDir = path.getRoot().resolve(path.subpath(1, path.getNameCount()));
System.out.println("resolved path: " + removedTopDir);
```